# Have different types of inputs in discord.py commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have different types of inputs in a discord.py command. For example when trying to lookup someone's profile you can either ping that person or type their user

Here is what I tried to do

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, user):

    if isinstance(user,str) == True:
        #input is str, look for player in the server
    else:
        #input is a player
```

I also tried using `user: discord.User` but that only works when mentioning someone

Comment: Looking for a username is a slow task in a large server, the easiest way is to just let them tag..

Comment: `user: discord.User` is a `discord.ext.commands.UserConverter`, which does work with a user id, username + discriminator, and username in addition to a mention. So, the easiest thing to do is probably just to use the user converter, or better yet, member converter if you need a `Member` instead of a `User`.

Comment: Well bots like dank memer do it, so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OP, all arguments that ever get passed to a commands will be strings if no converters are used. You can then use [MemberConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=memberconverter#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) or any other class you want to, `int` for example (make sure to sanitize input from any characters it should not have, by using regular expressions or string's `isdigit`, `isascii` and other methods)

For other readers, I recommend using [Pycord](https://pycord.dev/) or any other discord.py forks because they will probably support slash commands which allow users to literally pass in a member as an argument without having to ping him or copy their ID. [SlashCommandOptionType enum from pycord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/discord/enums.py#L622)
Edit: discord.py is back in development